# Validating (Django Rest Framework) Serializer Fields based on Request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to validate a DRF serializer CharField based on the Request object. The value supplied must be checked for uniqueness against other database values, that are filtered based on the Request.

I've tried setting a to_representation method, but that also runs when retrieving data.

Comment: This is a bit vague. Doesn't all data come from the request? Show what you want to do and what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bar = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    filter1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    filter2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate(self, data):
        print('bar value:', data.get('bar'))
        print('filter1 value:', data.get('filter1'))
        print('filter2 value:', data.get('filter2'))
        # Put your conditions and queries here and raise serializers.ValidationError() if they don't match
        return data
```

```
serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```